# Book recommendation lists

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

Among the C++ FAQ posts, there is a nice, wiki-style [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) with recommendations. This question has gotten some special love and attention from a diamond mod, to clear out all the clutter posts.

This is a petition to have the same done to the [C book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/562377#562377), which is currently rather messy. I'm however not sure whether such posts should be locked or not.

I would like some discussion about how we determine what books that are on lists like these. Until now, it seems pretty arbitrary what ends up there. There's been some questionable edits and I'm not at all sure about the quality of all the books.

Any suggestions for how we should maintain special posts such as these book lists? How to ensure that only quality books are recommended and that there are no "vandalism" edits where one's own personal favourite book is added at a whim?

Comment: I stumbled upon your question because I was hoping to find a **bookrecs.stackexchange**, similar to the [**softwarerecs.stackexchange**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Sadly, it seems not enough people see the need for this.

Comment: @Mentalist You came to the right place, this is the book recommendation site. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it).

Comment: Oh, heh... thanks but... I meant general book recommendations. Not exclusively technical reference books for programmers. (Which is what it seems is being curated here.) Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I take with @Lundin's answer is that the 'one per answer' rule is not maintanable, and it doesn't play to the strengths of a Q&A site where we strive to see one canonical answer instead of pages of equally valid answers.

We all know no one goes past the first page anyways.

If there's interest in maintaining that list, I'd be happy to put a wiki-lock on the question and clean up the other posts.  If there isn't interest from the community, then I don't see a need to intervene.

Answer (score 0):

Posts such as the C book list need some cleanup, but once that is done, I think the community can maintain the list themselves, in a democratic way, without involving diamond moderators.

This is my proposal:

- Leave the post unlocked, but protected. Meaning you can post, but you need some rep to do so.
- Any book on the list should have its corresponding answer, where only **one** book is listed.
- Every "book answer" should state the correct title and the author(s). Preferably with a link to where the book is available and also the [ISBN number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number). If possible, it should be mentioned which programming standard version of the language that the book covers.
- Every "book answer" must state the target audience for the book: **beginner**, **intermediate**, **advanced** or **reference style**.
- Every "book answer" should preferably be converted to a "community wiki".
- Depending on the number of up votes, a book may reach the list or get removed from it. The 5 posts within a certain category that have most up votes should be on the list. That is, the 5 most up-voted beginner books, the 5 most up-voted intermediate books and so on.
- This way, the community can maintain the list by themselves and it may live a dynamic life as more books are written.

Example of a "book answer":

---

*Reference style*

**[The C programming language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131103628)** (2nd edition) by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

C standard: ISO 9899:1990.

ISBN-13: 978-0131103627

Commonly known as "K&R", it is impossible to ignore this famous book for a list such as this. It is perhaps the most famous programming book ever written and contains the original "hello, world" example.

The first edition of the book had such impact that a de facto version of the programming language was named after it: "K&R C" typically refers to all C code written before ISO standardization. Once C became formally standardized, the book was revised in a second edition, with corrections that made it compatible with the standard.

It should be noted that this book is quite outdated and contains [many errors](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html), so whether or not it is still suitable as learning material is disputed. But it can certainly still be used as a language reference, or otherwise for nostalgia purposes.