# Delete more book lists!

Tags: support, status-declined, specific-question

The [list of books every programmer should read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) has now been thankfully deleted with [community support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books). But there's still a couple floating out there; I found these two very quickly but there may be more. They're both already locked, but we can do better!

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|22.4353)
- [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=2|4.5471)

Comment: Fair warning:  the C/C++ people will *eat you alive* for suggesting this.  Those lists are the exception that prove the rule.  They're protected on high by the Devil himself.  They're... eh, you get the idea.

Comment: Take into account that some of these lists are *actively being maintained*. The whole point of deleting that other list was that it was not.

Comment: They keep trying to delete the C++ book list. They keep failing.

Comment: I smell something tasty here...

Comment: RUN. RUN WHILE YOU STILL CAN. I CAN HEAR ANGRY BARKS FROM THE LOUNGE ALREADY!!!

Comment: Too war! or some such dramatic sounding action or not maybe, I don't care, time for a drink.

Comment: These lists are pretty much the complete *opposite* of the other ones - they are focused on one particular subject, they're organized well, they have links to the resources off-site, and they have descriptions of what they are about. They're also being actively maintained so they don't go stale. Not really comparable.

Comment: @Bart TOO LATE!

Comment: @animuson - Opposite as in the other one was vandalized and then locked, whereas this one was not locked and the community was allowed access to it?

Comment: @TravisJ These ones weren't locked because the community members that maintained them cared enough to prevent something like that from happening. The other one sat around for three years and **nobody said a word about it.** So yes, they are opposite in that regard as well.

Comment: @animuson - No one said a word about it? It was vandalized by the user random with the phrase "**crush kill destory (a hijack moment;**". 2 minutes later it was rolled back. There was an exchange of comments and literally at the end of the comment exchange the post was locked right then and there. Feb 21 was when comment requesting an explanation occurred and the last edit was placed. Mar 2nd it was locked, two weeks.. This post was also deleted and undeleted several times. It was discussed on meta **extensively** and the consensus then was to leave it locked and not deleted.

Comment: @animuson - Delete it with a wave of your hand, but in all honesty taking action all alone when there have already been large amounts of discussion these topics between users, trusted members, and moderators, is more than likely going to end up being overturned back to a group consensus and not just a single point of view.

Comment: @TravisJ One comment, which the person who made the comment ended up rolling back their own rollback. Also, where exactly has that particular question been discussed extensively? I see it's been mentioned a few times as an example for other issues, but I've never seen any sort of discussion about whether or not it should exist other than the one recently created here on Meta SO.

Comment: @TravisJ Users had three years to create that question to discuss its viability or that they wanted it unlocked so they could salvage it. It's too late for that now, though. The question has died off and there are already much better places to find that information online. Putting effort into reviving that question is just a waste of everyone's time, even moreso than discussing whether it should be deleted or not.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124392/178816

Comment: Voting to reopen because this isn't "no longer can be reproduced".  The questions still exist, but they are allowed to exist.  But users who object to this should be allowed to add answers to support their position

Answer (score 19):

The [c] and [c++] communities are a little different from most other tag communities.  Most contributors have been around for a very long time, are experienced programmers, know each other well and rarely stray from their tag.  Voting is very strong, good Q+A goes up fast, bad questions quickly disappear.

They do get pummeled by the "newbies", students that are learning the languages, peaks in November and April when the end-of-semester assignments are due.  They make all the typical mistakes that everybody makes, getting utterly stuck at simple programs that bomb or misbehave without a good diagnostic.

They don't *really* want to send them packing, everybody remembers their own struggle to become productive.  The book lists they maintain is their fallback.  Plenty of "read this and you'll get better at it" comments.

That isn't exactly what SO is about.  "Read a book" is not an answer and is not helpful.  Everybody knows that.  But it is not like other communities do it better, a downvote or a close vote for "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking" isn't any better.  Or just ignore the question completely, that's common today.  Really, it is worse.

What you can't deny them is that they actually have a productive and stable community.  So very, very unlike others, you can think of them without me mentioning their name, where contributors just give up in disgust.  Hey, maybe they're on to something.

Answer (score 13):

The point frankly isn't to delete book lists. The point is that book recommendation questions (in the form of lists or otherwise) generally don't work out all that well for reasons discussed at length over time.

The thing is however that the questions you list are about as good as the "bad thing" gets. Curated. Actively maintained. Well organized. Deleting them won't bring any benefit to the site.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the idea that we can do better.

For questions as important as these, we should have a higher level of locking that only allows the question to be edited or answered by users with a Gold badge in at least one of the tags on the question<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. If we wanted to add a special bonus, anybody who doesn't have at least one gold badge who suggests deleting said question would find their own user account summarily deleted. :-)</sup>

Comment: Related in spirit though not particulars: [my answer to "What privilege should 30k users get?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252861/)

Comment: Plus 1 for the bonus.