# Can a protected question be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, rules

I start by saying that I just want to understand better how SO works. I don't want to sound provocative to the slightest.

A stellar and protected question is the "[Definitive C++ book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)".

Maybe I don't put this in the right context, but that looks like a prime example of a "resource seeking" question and answers are recommendations. This is usually considered off-topic in practically all other cases, as "primarily opinion based".

Incidentally speaking, I feel rather uneasy as that particular question looks extremely valuable to me.

Yet it is a matter of opinion, although I happen to share the very same opinion underlining some very good answers: books written by language designers are a sound choice.

How do you regard this matter?

Should sometimes rules be "lenient" or are there historical and practical considerations which I am not aware of?

Comment: There have been meta discussions on that particular question before, actually. IIRC, that's how it came ot be wiki-locked in the first place. (That's what that is- A wiki-lock.) Basically, the C++ community is still actively maintaining the question, so the mods locked it in such a way as they can edit the existing answer but not add more. It's off-topic, but old, useful, and actively maintained, so it's stayed thus far.

Comment: Of course- One of the questions I was thinking of, by the way, can be found [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296094/delete-more-book-lists) Pretty sure there are more, but I don't have the time to do more searching.

Comment: Note that "protected" is different from the type of a lock put on that question. Protection can be done by anyone with enough imaginary points (3k/10k?), while all sorts of historical/special locks can be done only by diamond moderators. Indeed if your question would be "can protected question be off-topic" than answer yes - closing and protection are separate unrelated activities (also one may want to "protect" off-topic question if it takes time to close and q collects random answers from new users, which is very rare nowdays)

Comment: Also, just for reference, resource requests have their own close reason. `"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov 15k