# Can a question really be a duplicate of 'The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List'?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) which has lists of books and some questions(eg:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460728) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828324)) are duplicates of this question.

But I think it is quite weird to mark duplicate at this case. Since book recommendations is off topic now, is marking duplicate give users a wrong message that this type of questions is allowed here?

Some questions found seems trying to copy the idea of the question:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878823) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419715)

Comment: It's an exception, since the post is actively maintained by the members of the C++ community. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296094/delete-more-book-lists

Comment: My answer on "[Troubleshooting question wrongly closed as duplicate of "how to debug" reference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307326)" is somewhat related.

Answer (score 3):

I believe closing as duplicate of properly closed/marked off-topic question by gold-hammer is good alternative to waiting till 5 people vote as regular off-topic.

If you don't have gold-hammer - vote as regular off-topic (which is could have  happened on one question you've mentioned as it has 3 votes).

Note that this particular list is special case for C/C++ communities covered in [Delete more book lists!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296094/delete-more-book-lists). It sounds like community decided that duplicate to well-maintained list is better than simple off-topic.