# Why moderators handle questions with "historical significance" inconsistently?

Tags: discussion, revision-history, historical-lock

There is this question:

[What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1711/revisions)

Which has a rather interesting history:

```
    Post Deleted by animuson♦
    Question Unprotected by Jarrod Dixon♦   
    Notice added Historical significance by Jarrod Dixon♦   
    Post Locked by Jarrod Dixon♦    
    Post Undeleted by Jarrod Dixon♦ 
    Post Deleted by yoda, Adam Davis, Wooble, Conrad Frix, user7116, John Saunders, Ninefingers, joran, ChrisF♦, Matthias Bauch, Tim Cooper, Gilles, Konerak, meagar♦, Charles, Will    
    Notice removed Historical significance by Robert Harvey♦    
    Post Unlocked by Robert Harvey♦ 
    Post Undeleted by Robert Harvey♦    
    Question Protected by Community♦    
    Post Deleted by casperOne♦  
    Post Closed as "not constructive" by casperOne♦ 
    Notice added Historical significance by Robert Harvey♦  
    Post Locked by Robert Harvey♦   
    Post Unlocked by Robert Harvey♦
```

As you can see moderators trampled on each others' toes for a year then after 3 years of peaceful existence came another one and deleted it again. I actually linked this post a lot of times to other people and bookmarked it as reference and I don't see why it got deleted but the main problem is that moderator's can't seem to agree about these kind of questions?

I think there should be some kind of moderator guideline which tries to minimize the chance of this kind of infighting.

Another example:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions)

```
    Post Locked by Robert Harvey♦   
    Notice added Offtopic comments by Robert Harvey♦    
    Notice removed Historical significance by Robert Harvey♦    
    Post Unlocked by Robert Harvey♦
    Notice added Historical significance by Robert Harvey♦
    Post Locked by Robert Harvey♦
    Question Protected by Will
    Question Unprotected by Bill the Lizard 
    Question Protected by Bill the Lizard
```

I'm surprised that although this question is funny it was not deleted but according to the FAQ it should have been. What is the reason for this? If we allow questions with "historical significance" why do other moderators override it or outright delete the question?

So if we delete the first the second should also be deleted (with a lot others I did not link here) and vica versa.

Comment: That's not as much inconsistent as it is opinion-based. Moderators are human beings with different opinions (and the opinions of a given moderator can change with time). Trying to force them into a hive mind would be prone to failure I'm afraid.

Comment: "So if we delete the first the second should also be deleted (with a lot others I did not link here) and vica versa." - the first is a useless question asking for random books, answered by a list of random books. The second is a canonical question acting as a duplicate target for [over 6000 "I can has regex to parse XML/HTML/XHTML" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1732348?lq=1) and has valid answers that discuss why you shouldn't use RE in general, and when it actually is applicable. That the first answer is also the most popular SE meme is just a bonus.

Comment: It is nowhere near random. They are all useful books and the question is worth linking.

Comment: That's what I think as well. There was not even an explanation.

Comment: @AdamArold "It is nowhere near random" - the list included Alice in Wonderland and similar nonsense, how is that not random? Also, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books) for the discussion that led to the deletion, the answer by animusson pretty exhaustively covers the reasons why it should be deleted.

Comment: And you removed all context from those history entries. Those actions did not happen in isolation; the community around the site evolved too. What was the right action for the post at one point in time can be the wrong choice at another. To cast those changing tides as conflicts between moderators is misinterpreting the events.

Comment: Most of the books on the list are consistent. If 1% of the books are not you can't say it is random because of that 1%.

Comment: You ask for a rag-tag group of volunteers to act in absolute coordination?  You wonder why a loosely associated group of human beings don't act in perfect unison?  Sirrah, what species *are you?*

Comment: No matter what you say it seems that 37% of the users agree with me which is more than just a minority..

Answer (score 15):

You're looking at two very different questions and asking why they weren't handled consistently. I wonder why you think they would have been.

- The first is an old, off-topic question that survived on the site for way too long because we were tired of people asking for the same list of book recommendations every day. The list grew to the point of being useless, so the post was locked and eventually deleted.
- There was nothing wrong with the second question. I don't know what you find funny about it. It's locked because the top answer was drawing too much attention. It's been flagged over a hundred times, and several people tried to edit it to "fix" it because they didn't understand the joke.

These are two completely different cases, so again, why do you expect consistency from moderators?

Answer (score 1):

Because moderators, for the most part, are human beings.

You'll also find that being from different cultures and timezones means that having one blanket process that everyone follows 100% of the time is near-on impossible.

Comment: But if one moderator makes a decision why does another one override it?

Comment: @AdamArold - see: Moderators are human. further reading: Humans make mistakes and are subject to differences in opinion.

Comment: *for the most part*