# Histo-Locked "C++ IDE recommendations" post - shouldn't it be removed by now?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, historical-lock

Here's a historical post on SO:

[C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

This would be closed as inappropriate had it been asked today, but was kept for historical/social reasons. The problem is, the information in it is by now rather outdated - most answers are 6-7 years old, and things have changed since then. Since comments and edits cannot be made to update the answers or to qualify them, does this not tip the balance in favor of just removing the question?

**BEFORE UPVOTING THIS QUESTION, PLEASE NOTE THAT THE TOP-VOTED ANSWER CALLS FOR ACTION BASED ON A COMPARISON BETWEEN *THIS QUESTION'S* SCORE AND *THAT ANSWER'S* SCORE** -- so unless you read that answer, you'll be "voting" on a proposed solution without even knowing it.

Comment: A lot of people tend to raise hell whenever someone suggests deleting a "popular" question. I don't have any strong opinions about it either way, but I'd definitely be interested in hearing what other people have to say about it.

Comment: You have noticed that it's a _community wiki_ Q&A? Similar like the [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: It's been locked about ___4___ years ago. As far as IDEs are concerned, that's an eternity. The answers on there are simply outdated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's a faulty comparison, as the IDE post is histo-locked and thus uneditable, not wiki-locked and actively maintained.

Comment: SO doesn't want to remove old crap posts because they generate traffic. [Similar example of crap preservation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books). I honestly think the SO owners step in and slap non-employed diamond mods if they attempt to remove old crap.

Comment: Can we just get a moderator to burninate this?  To put it in more perspective, 4 years ago, Eclipse was still the darling of Java developers, with NetBeans fighting it out for some of Eclipse's mindshare.

Comment: @Makoto: And now it's the opposite?

Comment: @einpoklum:  I don't deny that it's still widely in use, but it's definitely not darling anymore.

Comment: I've added a notice to prevent anyone else from making the same mistake I did (see my comment on NathanOliver's answer).

Answer (score 25):

The last activity on that post occurred on Sep 29 '11 at 10:40 and that was [Jeff Atwood♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) locking it. I think this question has been static long enough and we really only have two ways forward.

1. Unlock it, Make a Community Wiki, Add it to the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) and then we can maintain and update it as technology/feature change.
2. Delete it and let it go.  If we are not going to be updating the information the it is losing more of its relevance each day.

Personally I think we should go with option 1 as I think it is a good resource and can definitely drive traffic.  If there is not enough community support for that then I say just delete it and let it go.

If you feel that the question should be saved and made a CW then vote for this answer to show support for that option. If you feel that it should just be deleted as [einpoklum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1593077/einpoklum) suggest then vote on the question.

Comment: I actually got to it looking for a C++ IDE recommendation on Google, which supports your point 1 (I think). Still, maybe it's worth it clearing the answers, or at least commenting on all the answers and telling the authors if they don't update them within X days they'll be removed.

Comment: To clarify: your option 2 (delete) is einpoklum's proposal. IOW, it doesn't make sense to Meta-vote both for the question and this answer. Vote on the question if you're in favor of deleting it, vote for this answer to keep the question wiki'ed

Comment: @MSalters I added a blurb to the end of the answer with that.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It does.

Comment: Tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic. If this thread is to be restored, we will also have to change the very SO rules and allow tool recommendation questions. So the sensible thing is to delete the post.

Comment: @Lundin Yes they are but there is precedence like [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @NathanOliver The various book recommendation threads are also similarly bad... I used to think they were good too, at some point, but I have now given up on them. They are subjective and list all kinds of crap books together with the good ones. I haven't read enough C++ books to judge the quality of the C++ book list, but the similar C book list contains _lot_ of crap books. I actually think these book lists cause more harm than good. We have to very frequently de-program people who have been damaged reading K&R and tell them how to actually write proper, modern C programs, for example.

Comment: @Lundin: The fact that the specific recommendations are good or bad is not actually the point... anyway, I think it would be better not to revive the question but rather just close it. SO gets enough traffic as it is.

Comment: @einpoklum Wait and see... if some diamond mod suddenly pops up here too and describes how tool recommendations for outdated IDEs hold immense value to mankind, then you know why.

Comment: keeping off-topic recommendation questions around just encourages people to post more of the same type of off-topic recommendations and use those that are kept around as a example of what to do.

Comment: @MSalters I'd interpret a vote for the question a "this (meta) question is worth considering", not "we should delete the question".

Comment: @Lundin: wiki-locking the book recommendation question actually ruined it.  The voting on the various recommendations was the most valuable part of the question, followed by the comments explaining exactly what's wrong with individual terrible answers.  Gone and gone.

Comment: Keep it?  For what?  What purpose does it serve now?  I'm willing to bet that a good chunk of those IDEs up there are either unsupported or don't exist anymore.  If all we're doing is counting the fact that this question has so many views, let's also consider the other angle which is the amount of misinformation provided by looking at this list.

Comment: If I upvote your answer and downvote the question, that's like voting two times for the same person... I feel like a cheater now...

Comment: It is likely that at least some people will read the question, think *now, that's a good question!* and upvote it without seeing the bottom of this answer that turns a vote for the question into a vote for a specific solution.

Comment: Correction: the last activity on the post was an answer upvote on [Heinrik Hartz's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50830/henrik-hartz) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/408842/3160466), on March 5th 2012.

Comment: @artofcode by activity I ment anything that changes the post.  Votes don't change the last modified.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah, fair enough. I'll call the vote the last event, then.

Comment: Maybe they should rename it: C++ IDE for Linux for time travel trip to 2011?

Comment: I didn't read the last line carefully and had already upvoted the question (because it's a good question). Now I've got locked-in upvotes on both the question *and* this answer. (@EricJ.: good call!) For the record, I'm in favor of making a new CW-answer.

Answer (score 2):

I put a Collaborative Lock on it.  This will allow you to update and maintain the existing top-rated answer, while still keeping the other benefits of locking the post (such as preventing new answers).

Comment: I'm not sure how that's supposed to work here. Many of the existing answers duplicate each other, and new IDEs exist today that weren't around when the question was created. How are we supposed to maintain the answers given these constraints?

Comment: @duskwuff it's a *community wiki*. Just edit and update the original question and a few select answers.

Comment: @Bob To do that, we'd have to edit some of the answers into completely different answers. That seems like a step too far for even a community wiki.

Comment: I agree with @duskwuff. And five days after you changed the lock, I still don't see *any* recent edits (at least on the first page of answers). I upvoted the answer that's the most "list-like", which is the most promising candidate for ongoing maintenance, but it's only the 4th-highest-ranked answer and is still nearly 150 votes behind the top-ranked answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand As far as I can tell, there has *still* not been any editing activity on this question. Simply put, this isn't working.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Is the question editable?  Just put a summary of all the answers in the question, with links to each answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a third option in the response of @NathanOliver.
I'm not saying that is the best option, but I guess that it's another good option.

3. **Move the question to [SoftwareRecs Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and open it**

When the OP made the question, this site did not yet exists (I think), so the SO was the only good option, but now we have a specific site to deal with this type of question.

A [quick search for "C++ IDE linux" in SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=C%2B%2B%20IDE%20linux) apparently does not show any results with the same criteria of the original question, so it looks like a good question to stay always updated in a right site.

Just FYI, [the site will be graduate soon](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating)

Note: The question "as is" could be consider off-topic in SoftwareRecs too, but this can be fixed with a simple edit.

Comment: Questions can only be migrated within 90 days after they're posted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Come on, you know this would qualify as an exception.