# How can I find the most bookmarked questions?

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

A bookmark represents a quite personal expression of (future?) value of a question (or rather the answers given) to a single user.

I wondered what the most bookmarked questions are, how I would be able to find them, and if they could be generally useful to discover new and interesting topics.

[Using existing sorting methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) is straightforward, but I couldn't find a way to sort by number of bookmarks.

A quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=most%20bookmarked%20questions%20on%20stack%20overflow) and [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=most%20bookmarks) search also did not bring up anything about the topic.

Comment: Bear in mind that one main reason that the name was changed from Favorites to Bookmarks is that many people use(d) them to mark bad questions (or pages with bad answers), not just pages with good content. But I guess that usage is less likely these days, now that we can follow posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this data explorer [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1378063). Bookmarks (called favorite till 6 to 8 weeks ago) are stored in the Votes table as a row with votetypeid = 5. It is one one of the few rows in the votes table that has its userid column populated, allowing for some fun but useless insights.

```sql
select top 1000
       postid as [Post Link]
     , count(*) [Bookmarked] 
from votes
where votetypeid = 5 -- favorite
group by postid
order by count(*) desc
```

when run today, this is your result:

[image: top bookmarked question list]

The 194812 is this [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) [screenshot for < 10 k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyLnO.jpg) [We're not going to undelete it! Just don't!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295495)

Also fun: The users that bookmarked the most questions (the second result set in the query):

[image: users that bookmark most]

Even more fun: The users that got the most bookmarks (third resultset):

[image: users that many bookmarks]

Comment: Can <10k mortals like me get a screenshot of that question, please :)

Comment: @Yatin I'm not going to screenshot 331 answers spread over 12 pages but I've added the first page of answers. You'll be thrilled ...

Comment: How could 35k bookmarks ever be helpful to anyone?

Comment: @Dharman over the years I've learned to not try to find rhyme or reason in how others use the site. I've trouble enough to keep myself on-track.