# Do we need [effective-c++]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

There is [effective-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effective-c%2b%2b) tag. Currently it has 80 questions.

Its tag info states:

> Tag for implementing and understanding guidelines and recommendations
> in any of the books "Effective C++: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your
> Programs and Designs", "More Effective C++: 35 New Ways to Improve
> Your Programs and Designs", "Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to
> Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14", or "Effective STL: 50 Specific
> Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library",  by Scott
> Meyers.

Criteria for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
   applied? And is it unambiguous?

   According to the tag info, there are several different books on different topics which makes it ambiguous enough. Also effective is rather broad term and all kinds of things can be put under the effective umbrella.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Definition of effective is too broad and not focused even when constrained to single language. It is about writing effective code (what does that even mean? Fast, easy to maintain code...) being effective in writing code, being effective designing the APIs or larger systems...
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No, certainly not.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Since it covers several books it does not clearly describe same thing in all common contexts.
5. Can someone be an expert in effective C++?

   Not really. You can be expert in C++. Being expert in effective C++ is meaningless.

---

Additionally, we don't have tags for books, authors, companies as they don't add any meaningful information to the post. Any code concepts and tricks that may be described in any of those books will clearly fall under the C++ tag and general coding practices. Question must stand on its own even without the book reference.

Comment: *"Additionally, we don't have tags for books"* - there is a first time for everything.

Comment: @Gimby Neat, I wrote three books, maybe I can start my own tag ;)

Comment: (Impressive!). I'd be more interested in a meta post discussing if such tags have value first though :) Cody makes a fair point for this incredibly specific book tag, but that does not imply they should just be created on a whim. This seems more like an exception to the rule, but I can't speak for others.

Comment: Perhaps it is comparable to patterns (and anti-patterns)? - an inventory of things to do (only if in the prescriptive camp), look out for, check for, avoid, or refer to (a glossary of sorts). (Not a rhetorical question.) *"Initialisation order of globals? Ah, Scott Meyer's 36th."*

Comment: Only 80 questions but there are doubtless many more to which the tag *could* be added. I've certainly come across a few, and never even noticed that the tag existed. But low usage is not, in itself, a reason for burnination, IMHO.

Comment: @AdrianMole I agree that low usage is not a reason for burnination. But low usage combined with ambiguity (beyond it is a book series). I don't know what effective means.  It is a catch phrase. It is good for a book title, but IMHO it is not a good tag.

Comment: Still sounds a lot like the argument that we shouldn't have tags named for non-venomous constrictor snakes because people will get confused.

Comment: @PeterMortensen In that regard, effective-anything could be just replaced with pattern or anti-pattern.

Comment: "Additionally, we don't have tags for books, " - [tag:effective-java]. I'd find more, but tag search is useless

Comment: I assume you know this, @Zoe, but Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* series of books was inspired by Scott Meyers's *Effective C++* series. It's a great format, and it should exist for more languages.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe I should reconsider my approach and start writing "Effective Delphi" series ;)

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't, I've yet to read a single programming book :p my point was purely that we _do_ have tags for books. Whether we _should_ is a different question I'm not addressing

Comment: And people keep telling me that Delphi is dead so I should stop using/supporting it.

Comment: @user4581301 Still alive and kicking...

Comment: (The author, Scott Meyers, is not to be confused [Erik Meijer](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f), the functional programming guy with *"a bunch of presentations where he trashes Agile while using this weird coloured shirt"*. [Sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2u0sNRO-QKQ).)

Answer (score 10):

This tag refers to *a specific book series* written by Scott Meyers.

Yes, programming questions about the content in that book can (and should) *also* be tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), but that doesn't mean that the tag [effective-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effective-c%2b%2b) is problematic. It is a useful way to categorize and find questions specifically about Scott Meyers's *Effective C++* series of books, which are quite popular.

Comment: Maybe books are popular, but 80 questions in 14 years does not scream popular to me. At least it does not do anything for easier locating of answers.

Comment: What's the issue with it being a relatively low-usage tag? I'm not following. Importantly, what I'm *not* seeing is evidence of widespread misuse.

Comment: It promotes poor tag usage. And then it may create problems if "bad" tag becomes too popular. Additionally, I landed to the tag through recently asked question where efective-c++ was the only tag. If you don't have bad tags offered out of the box, more appropriate tags would be used. But, I understand your point.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar was the question answered? If it wasn't, then that means that the tag is causing real harm. Most of the question's I've found the tag was added post-facto, and many answered without the tag. So, at best, the tag didn't do anything.

Comment: @Braiam No, the question wasn't answered. I added the c++ tag and voted to close. At the end it was closed as unclear and author deleted it.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think you made the usual mistake thinking SO is a programming site. While in fact SO is a programming and book review site. We love here books, apparently. [See this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books).

Answer (score 2):

We don't have tags for:

- Companies (with a single notable exception, [Sony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony) and even then that exception is exceptional: tons of products, not many questions, and **active engagement of Sony employees**)
- Code challenges, no exceptions
- Websites

This tag seems [more of the later two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71642277/792066), rather than the former. You can ask about it, but I don't need to have read the books to answer them (or participate on the challenge itself). Heck, it seems that many of the answerers haven't read it either or [disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591698/792066) by the author itself. Also, I don't think that just because it's popular we need to create a tag for it. There's tons of popular, yet wrong or misleading, text online. Would we also create tags for those?

Better keep tags for what they are: connecting experts to those that are able to answer them. [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) seems to be doing that just fine, since most of those questions added the effective-c++ tag post factum, when they were already answered.

Comment: BTW, and this is kinda funny, [this question was asked with the c++11 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49423512/timeline), only to be later added the effective-c++ tag. But no one, until today, edited in the c++ tag. If it gets answered or closed for adding that tag, then that's pretty darn evidence that these tags don't fulfill the main purpose they should have.

Comment: We do have, for example, a [cs50] tag about a popular programming course. That one drew over 2500 questions and inspired a beta SE site.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I cannot say I am huge fan of that tag either. Imagine the chaos if all programming courses would get their tag. We should think about consequences if exceptions would be broadly applied. Of course, there are far worse tags, which really incentivize posting off topic questions.